# Is it possible to use Google Apps Marketplace with Oauth2 and OpenID

Tags: oauth, openid, oauth-2.0, google-openid, google-apps-marketplace

I have website which uses Oauth2 for communication with Google APIs. And it works fine.
Now i need to make it "Google Marketplace compliant" to be listed there. Googles docs says about Oauth or Federated Login, but it doesn't precised if Oauth2 works too.

Does anyone has experience in such integration? May i keep Oauth2 and add OpenID to work with Marketplace, or i have to rework it for Federated Login?

Thanks!

Comment: oAuth2 - no. oAuth1 (2-Legged) - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you list your app in the marketplace, you will get a consumer key and secret which you can use for 2-Legged OAUTH for every google apps domain that installed your app. So the answer is YES.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is NO as of July 9, 2012. `Google is in the process of adding OAuth2 for Apps Marketplace` https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v1/marketplace#oauth2

Comment: the answer is NO to what ? You still CAN install in the market place and use the consumer key/secret to access resources using 2legged oauth.

Comment: The no is with respect to being able to use OAuth2 with the market place.  When you register an app on the marketplace you get OAuth credentials, not OAuth2 credentials (not supported yet).  So the No is citing "if OAuth2 works too".  Sorry my answer wasn't more precise.  He can keep OAuth2, but will have to re-implement authentication in OAuth with his marketplace credentials.

Comment: Well, I use the marketplace credentials with com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.CredentialStore.class. My app supports both individual Google accounts and Google Apps accounts with OAUTH2. Proof by example ?

Comment: @koma oAuth2 is not yet supported for Google Marketplace installed apps. oAuth2 calls require a consumer key, consumer secret and a whitelisted **redirect URL**. You get all these by registering the project in the Google API Console, but the Marketplace does not provide them out of the box.